# How use commitlint only for subject-case setentence case and body-full-stop never

Tags: git-commit, husky, commitlint

I am trying to use commitlint without using `extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional'],`:

```
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'subject-case': [2, 'always', 'sentence-case'],
    'type-empty': [2, 'always'],
    'body-full-stop': [2, 'never', '.'],
  },
}
```

But with this config I still be able to do: `$ git commit -m 'hello.'` but I expect, that "." in the end is forbidden, also I expect small letter is start of message is forbidden also.

What am I doing wrong?